# Unable to inject dependency in fragment using dagger2 in Java Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am able to inject dependency in activities and its working fine. but calling the same dependency in fragment is not taking access.

This is what i did.

App.Java

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication implements HasActivityInjector, HasFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector;

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentInjector;

    private AppComponent mComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
    mComponent.inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
    return activityInjector;
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentInjector() {
    return fragmentInjector;
    }
}
```

This is AppComponent.Java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AndroidInjectionModule.class, ActivityModule.class, FragmentModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<App> {

    void inject(App app);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    Builder application(Application application);
    AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

This is ActivityModule.Java class

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract MainActivity contributeMainActivityInjector();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract MyActivity contributeCampaignActivityInjector();
}
```

this is FragmentModule.java class

```
@Module
public abstract class FragmentModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract MyFragment bindMyFragment();
}
```

Now in my MyFragment class where i want to inject that dependency. on top i add these lines inside class

```
@Inject
ImageDownloaderApi imageDownloaderApi;
```

then to check in onCreateView function i did this to check if my dependency is working like this

```
boolean injected = imageDownloaderApi == null ? false : true;
    Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Dependency worked: "+ String.valueOf(injected));
```

And it is returning me false everytime.

where as same code works in activites. 
one more thing i am doing in activities is adding this line below onCreate like this

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);    // this line
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

when in trying to add the same line in onCreateView in fragment

```
AndroidInjection.inject(this);
```

it states red line below this. and if i replace this with getActivity. it gave me runtime error.

Please have a look and guide where i am wrong?

Is the process i am doing for fragment is right or not?. as it is clearly working in activities.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using `Fragment`-s from support library. Try to change `public class App extends MultiDexApplication implements HasActivityInjector, HasFragmentInjector` to `public class App extends MultiDexApplication implements HasActivityInjector, HasFragmentInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector` with subsequent providing of appropriate injector.

[This is an easy article](https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe) that makes this topic clear. Also, `HasSupportFragmentInjector` interface usage is also described here.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey for help.
I am getting this error whild doing so == 
"java.lang.NullPointerException: com.arteciate.arteciate.di.App.supportFragmentInjector() returned null"

Comment: Have you implemented `public AndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector()` so it returns valid injector?

Answer (score 2):

> when in trying to add the same line in onCreateView in fragment
>
> AndroidInjection.inject(this);

this should be done in `onAttach` of your fragment, and if you are using the fragment from the support library, as you should, the line would  be `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)`

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
    super.onAttach(context)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Blackbelt. I forgot to add this on post. i also tried this. 
Now after your comment i add AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this) in onAttach of MyFragment. Getting this issue.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector was found for 
com.arteciate.arteciate.fragments.MyFragment
  

      at 
dagger.android.support.AndroidSupportInjection.findHasFragmentInjector(AndroidSupportInjection.java:92)

        at 
dagger.android.support.AndroidSupportInjection.inject(AndroidSupportInjection.java:57)


        at com.arteciate.arteciate.fragments.HomeArtworksFragment.onAttach(HomeArtworksFragment.java:252)
        at 

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1363) ..... so on

Comment: `HasFragmentInjector` should be declared on the Activity hosting the fragment iirc